# Oracle query `select some_name(?) from dual`. What is `some_name` and how to view the source?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, rdbms

I am looking at an already existing code base which connects to an Oracle database. It contains the query that looks like `select some_name(?) from dual`. What is `some_name` here? Is it a stored procedure? How can I view the source code for that function?

Comment: `select some_name(?) from dual` this doesnot connect to Oracle. Not sure from where you get this. You must read from a authenticated source. You can try using `CONNECT` to connect to ORACLE

Comment: @XING I am already connected to Oracle database, and then the query is executed. Maybe my wording confused you.

Comment: Then you should use `select 1 from dual`. Dual is a dummy table having 1 row and 1 column. This is used to test which always return what you select. btw `some_name(?)` is nothing but a user defined function which user would had created to test his function.

Comment: `some_name(?)` most likely is a function. You can check this querying against user dictionary tables: `SELECT * FROM user_objects
where object_name = 'SOME_NAME'`. You can get a body of this function using: `SELECT * FROM all_source
WHERE NAME = 'SOME_NAME'`

Comment: @krokodilko thanks. But the query you provided does not return any rows. Could it be that I don't have access? When I run my query (the one given in the title) it returns a value, so I am sure it exists.

Comment: try this: desc some_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have SQLDeveloper, you can view the source code of SOME_NAME function in the function section, or TOAD, you can find it in the Schema Browser,

or you can query it using below select statement,

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_source
 WHERE name = 'SOME_NAME'
 ORDER BY line;
```